# Error: Expecting '}' but was: 'for'

Tags: apex

I have a trigger and from the trigger I am calling the class. While saving the class, i am getting the error-"***Expecting '}' but was: 'for'***"

The error is pointing at line# 19 of the apex class in the for loop.
for(Lead ld:Trigger.new){

ApexTrigger:

```
trigger leadTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    if((trigger.isAfter) && (trigger.isInsert)){
       LeadTriggerHelperClass.CreateAccount(Trigger.new);             
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHelperClass {
   
    public static void CreateAccount(List<Lead> leadobjs){
         Set<string> emailSet = new Set<string>(); 
         for(Lead ldobj : leadobjs){
            if(ldobj.email != null)
            emailSet.add(ldobj.email);                 
            }           
        
 Map<String, Account> emailMap = new Map<String, Account>();
    List<Account> accLst = [SELECT ID, Name,Email__c FROM Account where Email__c In : emailSet];
        if(accLst.size()>0){
            for (Account a : accLst)
              emailMap.put(a.Email__c,a);
        }
    
    }
   List<Account> accountsToBeUpdated = new List<Account>();
    for(Lead ld:Trigger.new){
        Account acc = new Account;
        if(emailMap.size()>0 && emailMap.containsKey(ld.Email)){
            acc = emailMap.get(a.Email);
            acc.Name = ld.LastName; 
            accountsToBeUpdated.add(acc);
        }
        else{
            acc.Name = ld.LastName;
            acc.Email__c = ld.Email;
            accountsToBeUpdated.add(acc);
        }
        
        if(accountsToBeUpdated.size()>0)
          upsert accountsToBeUpdated;  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a number of problems with this code. Here's an optimized version for you:

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHelperClass {
    public static void CreateAccount(List<Lead> leadobjs) {
        Map<String, Account> emailMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        // Get all the emails here
        for(Lead ldobj : leadobjs) {
            emailMap.put(ldobj.email, null);
        }
        // Ingore null email
        emailMap.remove(null);
        // Query all matching accounts
        for (Account a : [SELECT Email__c FROM Account where Email__c In :emailMap.keySet()]){
            emailMap.put(a.Email__c,a);
        }
        for(Lead ld:leadobjs) {
            if(ld.Email == null) {
                continue; // Skip null emails
            }
            Account acc = emailMap.get(a.Email);
            // Create a new account
            if(acc == null) {
                emailMap.put(ld.Email, acc = new Account(Email__c=ld.Email));                
            }
            acc.Name = ld.LastName;
        }
        upsert emailMap.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, On a different side, how are you posting the code. What is the posting process, i am getting the maximum character limitation error?

Comment: @MKD You're limited to 32,000 characters in a post (question or answer). This is way under that limit. Also, I use tabs instead of spaces when possible (I copy-paste from an IDE configured to use tabs by default).

Comment: @MKD As an aside, we strongly discourage posting the **entire** code of anything. You should include only relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors don't always point directly to the problem. A syntax error indicates that the compiler doesn't understand your code, and that lack of understanding sometimes does not point directly at the first problem or state the nature of the first issue.

**Edit**: I misidentified the problem myself. You have at least two syntax errors.

One is this:

```
for(Lead ld:Trigger.new){
    Account acc = new Account;
```

You are missing the required parentheses: `new Account();`

The other is that your closing brace two lines above actually closes the method, so your code thereafter is outside a method body:

```
} // <-- this closes the method body
List<Account> accountsToBeUpdated = new List<Account>();
for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) { // <-- this code can't be outside a method.
```

This reinforces my other recommendation. Your code is formatted in a way that makes it extremely difficult to follow its logical structure and flow of control, *even for you!* You should always use braces on your control structures, and consistently indent your code. The mess of indentation and bracing here made it difficult to see that your code's logical structure is not valid.

A code formatter such as Prettier can assist you in maintaining a standardized format, but it's also part of the discipline of writing and reading good, maintainable, understandable code. It's a favor both to your future self and any collaborator you might have now or in the future!

Comment: Thanks David. I will follow your suggestion.  I made modification in the code, but still the same error is popping up.   ```  for(Lead ld:Trigger.new){
        Account acc = new Account();    ```

Comment: I made few changes as suggested. Now i am getting new error in line# 18: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Lead `  for(Lead ld:Trigger.new)`

Comment: How to post the entire code. I am getting the maximum character limitation while posting in StackExchange.

Comment: @MKD Respectfully, I don't think we can go through errors one by one in a comment thread. I think you'll probably find some helpful questions on SFSE if you search - you'll need to cast your trigger context variables to the correct type. Although it would be better if you used a framework that accepts them as parameters, and access them directly only in the trigger body.

Answer (score 0):

You for loop is written outside a method body.Write for loop inside method to resolve the issue.